# WIX; How can I pass the [installfolder] as argument in an ExePackage

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I am creating a WIX bundle which calls an executable.
In that call I'm trying to pass the installfolder as an argument but for some reason this doesn't seem to work.

The bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <Bundle Name="$(var.Department) $(var.ProductName)"
            Version="!(bind.packageVersion.Database.CLI.Verify)"
            Manufacturer="$(var.Company) $(var.Department)"
            UpgradeCode="5fc4dc21-0202-4e28-b8a4-b87f972ae32e"
            DisableRemove="yes" 
            DisableModify="yes"
            IconSourceFile="Database.ico">

        <util:RegistrySearchRef Id='VerifyDotnetVersion' />

        <Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="c:\$(var.Company)"/>

        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
            <!-- LicenseUrl intentionally empty. -->
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl=""
                                                    LogoFile="Database.png"
                                                    SuppressOptionsUI="no"
                                                    SuppressRepair="yes"/>
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
        
        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="SqlServer2019ExpressLocalDB" />
            <PackageGroupRef Id="Database.CLI"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>
        <util:FileSearch Id='VerifyDotnetVersion'
                         Variable="DotnetVersion"
                         Path="dotnet.exe"
                         Result="version" />
        <bal:Condition Message="This installer requires at least dotnet version 6.">
            DotnetVersion >= v6
        </bal:Condition>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And the part that is calling the ExePackage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <Fragment>
        <PackageGroup Id="Database.CLI">

            <ExePackage Id="Database.CLI.Verify"
                        DisplayName="Check whether SqlLocalDb has been installed."
                        SourceFile="$(var.SourceFile)"
                        InstallCommand="verify"
                        UninstallCommand="remove"
                        Vital="yes"
                        Compressed="no"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="no">
                <ExitCode Value="0" Behavior="success" />
                <ExitCode Value="1" Behavior="error" />
                <ExitCode Value="5" Behavior="error" />
                <ExitCode Value="31" Behavior="error" />
                <ExitCode Value="183" Behavior="success" />
                <ExitCode Value="574" Behavior="error" />
                <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
            </ExePackage>

            <ExePackage Id="Database.CLI.Attach"
                        DisplayName="Attach database to the SqlLocalDb instance."
                        SourceFile="$(var.SourceFile)"
                        InstallCommand="attach Target=&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]\$(var.Department)\$(var.ProductName)&quot;"
                        Vital="yes"
                        Compressed="no"
                        PerMachine="yes">
                <ExitCode Value="0" Behavior="success" />
                <ExitCode Value="1" Behavior="error" />
                <ExitCode Value="5" Behavior="error" />
                <ExitCode Value="31" Behavior="error" />
                <ExitCode Value="183" Behavior="success" />
                <ExitCode Value="574" Behavior="error" />
                <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
            </ExePackage>

        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

When I look in the logs I see as argument:
`[7A60:546C][2022-06-16T16:44:15]i301: Applying execute package: Database.CLI.Attach, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\0FD93FB1FD9BBE5B46CC123351ECE9DBCEC54E9D\Database.CLI.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\0FD93FB1FD9BBE5B46CC123351ECE9DBCEC54E9D\Database.CLI.exe" attach Target="\Analytics\Database"'`
But I'm missing the contents of the `[INSTALLFOLDER]` so what I expect should be something like Target="c:\temp\Analytics\Database".

What am I missing here?

p.s. Is it also possible to provide an INSTALLFOLDER when launching the setup-bundle for silent installs? Like `Database.Setup.exe InstallLocation=c:\temp`

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to use command-line arguments by setting the `bal:Overridable="yes"` on the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burn variables are case-sensitive, so use `[InstallFolder]`, not `[INSTALLFOLDER]`.